# Из динамического символьного массива извлечь цифровые символы

Tags: c, массивы, char

Что-то я намудрил с типами(и не только), вообщем объявил функцию, в которой создается второй символьный динамический массив, проверяем изначальный массив на наличие цифрового символа, если таковой имеется, то присваиваем его второму массиву `

```
                #include <stdio.h>
                #include <stdlib.h>

           char remove(char* charac, int size, int index)
           {
            char *temp;
            int numbofindex = 0;
            temp = malloc((size) * sizeof(char*));
            for(int i = 0; i <size ; ++i)
            if(charac[i] >= '0' && charac[i] <= '9')
               {
                  temp[numbofindex] = charac[i];
                  numbofindex++;
               }
           printf("\nЦифровой ряд: %s\n", temp);
           free (charac); 
           }


        int main(void) 
         {
          char c, *charac;
          charac = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
          if(charac == NULL) {
             printf("Вы ничего не ввели!");
          exit(1);
         }
        printf("Введите символы(закончив нажми Enter): ");
        int i = 0;
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n') 
          {
             realloc(charac, (sizeof(char)));
             charac[i++] = c;
          }

        printf("\nСимвольный ряд: %s\n", charac);
       }`
```

Comment: И какая ошибка у вас получается?

Comment: А по приведенному коду, `man 3 malloc`, `man 3 isdigit`, `man 3 getline`. **Но** в самом начале  конечно же `man 3 realloc`. У вас написано как сделать UB.